# Cannot create Android Virtual Device in Android Studio in Ubuntu

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, virtual-machine

At the end of setup of adding virtual device(after selecting the Device & android version,) when I click on finish. I see the following error in the console
[Find the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAf8M.png)

note that the problemis notdue to the spaces in the name of device, I have tried it, still did not work.

NOTE : I am using Android studio in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with KVM installed on a Dell laptop with 4xIntel Core i5-3337U CPU @1.80Ghz.

Comment: which version of android studio are you using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*.ini file will be created when you creating a emulator in android studio. I think `/.android/avd` file location have not permission to create that file.

So,

Apply permission to this folder. then create into New

```
sudo chmod 777 .android
```

After that create it. It will working. :)